# how to map array type data in a object

Tags: arrays, reactjs

[image]

i try this code to show that data

```js
{comments !==null && comments.map(({comment})=>{
                        <div class="flex" key={comment.commentId}>
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 mr-3">
                                <img class="mt-2 rounded-full w-8 h-8 sm:w-10 sm:h-10" src={comment.userImg} alt={comment.userName} />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-1 border rounded-lg px-4 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4 leading-relaxed">
                                <strong>{comment.userName}</strong> <span class="text-xs text-gray-400">3:34 PM</span>
                                <p class="text-sm">{comment.comment}</p>        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    })}
```

and

```js
const[comments, setcomments] = useState([]);
    useEffect( ()=> {
        if (id) {
            DB.collection("blogs").doc(id).get().then((snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.data().comments;
                setcomments(data);
            });
        }
    },[id]);
```

but its shows this error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

please help me to solve that problem

Comment: Evidently snapshot.data() returns something that has no comments property, but without a [mre] it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Could `comments` be `undefined` rather than literal `null`? You could change your check to `comments != undefined && comments.map...` to handle both.

Answer (score 0):

You have an Array named comments. And it consists of objects. You are trying to get the **comment**'s value. But it is not exists in your API.

```js
{comments !==null && comments.map(({comment})=>{ // there is no object called comment, there is an object 
    <div class="flex" key={comment.commentId}>
         <div class="flex-shrink-0 mr-3">
              <img class="mt-2 rounded-full w-8 h-8 sm:w-10 sm:h-10" src={comment.userImg} alt={comment.userName} />
         </div>
         <div class="flex-1 border rounded-lg px-4 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4 leading-relaxed">
              <strong>{comment.userName}</strong> <span class="text-xs text-gray-400">3:34 PM</span>
              <p class="text-sm">{comment.comment}</p>        
          </div>
    </div>                        
})}
```

When you have an Array inside of *comments* array, you could use

```js
const comments = [{
  comment: [],
  date: [],
  etc: []
}]

comments.map(({comment, data, etc})=>(
    return ...
))
```

In the example above inside a map you are getting its values by destructing. Like that ...

```js
const obj = {name: "Abek", age: undefined}

const {name, age} = obj
```

You can try this code )

```js
{comments !==null && comments.map((item)=>{  
    <div class="flex" key={item.commentId}>
         <div class="flex-shrink-0 mr-3">
              <img class="mt-2 rounded-full w-8 h-8 sm:w-10 sm:h-10" src={item.userImg} alt={item.userName} />
         </div>
         <div class="flex-1 border rounded-lg px-4 py-2 sm:px-6 sm:py-4 leading-relaxed">
              <strong>{item.userName}</strong> <span class="text-xs text-gray-400">3:34 PM</span>
              <p class="text-sm">{item.comment}</p>        
          </div>
    </div>                        
})}
```

And I would suggest you when working with react you need to use classNames...

```js
const arrIterator = (arr) => {
  arr.map(item=>(
    <div className="d-flex">
      {item.name}
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @abek01, but its not working . i found other solution.  by Changing map(() => {}) to map(() => ())

{} - Creates a code block that expects an explicit return statement.
With () - implicit return takes place.

Comment: Sorry for this. I forgot that return keyword was returning JSX. When return works with JSX you need to use **()** brackets like that.